# How to display a Rest API call in swiftUI?

Tags: swift, rest, swiftui

I am following a tutorial for a simple Rest API call for a swiftui app, but when trying to ping another api I am unable to decode and show the response.

The only things changed from the tutorial are the API call and changing the model id as the api doesn't return an id.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var results = [TaskEntry]()
  
    var body: some View {
        List(results, id: \.id) { item in
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text(item.quote)
            }
        }.onAppear(perform: loadData)
    }
    
  
    func loadData() {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://api.kanye.rest") else {
            print("Your API end point is Invalid")
            return
        }
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            if let data = data {

                if let response = try? JSONDecoder().decode([TaskEntry].self, from: data) {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        print(response)
                        self.results = response
                    }
                    return
                }
            }
        }.resume()
    }
    
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

```
import Foundation

struct TaskEntry: Codable  {
    let id: UUID
    let quote: String
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your Rest API does not return `id` then I assume your response is not decoded to your `TaskEntry` type.

Try the following

```
struct TaskEntry: Codable  {
    let id = UUID()
    let quote: String
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case quote = "quote"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If any field can be not provide by api, it shoud be optional value.
If not, it will not find value to pass keypath to your struct/class

```
struct TaskEntry: Codable  {
    let id: UUID? // mark as optional value
    let quote: String
}
```